# How to change id data type from INT to string safely using Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to change an id entity from int to string. I already create the database but it does not have data yet.

```
public class Workflow
{
     public int ID { get; set; }
     /* it was first created as a int "public int Status { get; set; }" now I want to change it to string */
     public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your database isn't been used by other systems or doesn't impact other areas in your app, then you can change your `field` type to a `varchar` or to whatever type that represents a `string`. Then once you've changed that, you can then update your C# code and replace the type from `int` to a `string`. You could run a `migration` to reflect the changes from your schema to your code and vise versa:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/

Now, if the change will make a big impact to other systems or in your code, then I would recommend you to leave it as is and just do a code conversion when you want a `string` representation of the `ID` value.